# How can you detect the native browser shutdown in a Blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, browser, java-me

I've got a Blackberry app (5.0 and above) that I'm making changes to.  One feature of the app launches an online banking function in a BrowserField2.  I'm investigating a change to the app that would have the online banking function launch in the native browser, using this basic function:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(myBankingUrl);
```

The change is mostly motivated by performance -- the BrowserField2 seems a lot slower than the external browser.

My show-stoppper is this: in the existing implementation, I can detect when the BrowserField2 screen is shut down, and I can force the invocation of a logout call.  The bank that's associated with the online banking function really really cares about this.  I have not yet found any way to hook in to the shutdown of the external browser to port over this piece of functionality.  Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to detect that. You can listen when your app is activated - if you open browser your app screen is second in stack and becomes first when user closes first. But there is no garante that user will close browser or move to another app (to view incoming sms for example).
I would suggest you to continue with BrowserField2 for 5.0+.

Comment: Oh well.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The browser on a BlackBerry is always running. It provides the default push service reception and other required services.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about it. Can you show me a reference that has information on this. I will upvote when you answer -:)